# How to require interface members for response data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the code below (it compiles just fine), it was my expectation that any response data that did not conform to the interface IStory, would throw an error. However, this is not the case, and all the data is put in state normally. But there is certainly no `thisPropertyDoesNotExist` property on any of the response objects. Why isn't the interface being required here? How would that standard be implemented?

The end goal is for the response data to have at least the data defined in the interface (I'm really interested in checking if url's are not present).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getStory } from "../services/hnAPI";

interface Props {
  storyId: number;
}

interface IStory {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  url: string;
  thisPropertyDoesNotExist: string;
}

export const Story: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [story, setStory] = useState<IStory | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getStory(props.storyId)
      .then((data: Required<IStory>) => {
        data && setStory(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setStory(null);
      });
  }, [props.storyId]);
  return story ? (
    <p>
      <a href={story.url}>{story.title}</a>
    </p>
  ) : null;
};
```

Comment: Interfaces don't exist during runtime, when its transpiled to javascript. You only have the plain objects. The best solution I know is to use `obj.hasOwnProperty("thisPropertyDoesNotExist")` to check if a certain property exists or not. I don't think there is any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The end goal is for the response data to have at least the data defined in the interface (I'm really interested in checking if url's are not present).

Interfaces for json objects are just your promises (not validated at runtime) that the data will match what you say it will. TypeScript does not exist at runtime (its just JavaScript) and you cannot use interfaces are runtime.

## Solution

You can however write *JavaScript* validation code that
* Returns a type to TypeScript 
* Ensures the object matches the type

An example of such a library is: https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes

Comment: Ahh, interesting! Thanks for the helpful library tip!